# "index.php" in google index, rewrite url with slim

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, slim, google-index

I am working on a website which implements Slim. All my category urls are defined in a sitemap and a page which describes all the structure with links. But I don't precise the urls of the articles in the categories of my sitemap. 
My webesite is on production and Google indexes al the articles. But the urls in google are like

```
wrong url : www.domain.com/index.php/category/blabla/article-title
```

instead of

```
good url : www.domain.com/category/blabla/article-title
```

In the website, when you click on a link to display an article, the url in the nacigator is the good one. It makes the wrong url only in the google index. I don't know where it comes from, could someone tell me please ? Here is the code of the url :

```
$app->group('/' . $ed->nomXML . '/', $handleMenu(), function () use ($app, $rubriques, $ed) {

    //display article
    $app->get($formatRubrique.'/evenements/:id/:titre', function ($id, $titre) use ($app) {
         $ctrl = new ArticleController();
         $ctrl->viewArticle($app, $id);
    });
}
```

and the code of .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

To [permanently redirect](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301) your wrong urls to good urls, you can use the following redirect in .htaccess :

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index\.php/(.+)$ /$1
```

Comment: I already made a redirections, but thanks a lot, I just wanted to know where it comes from, to prevent wrong urls to be indexed. and I just saw that google actually indexed my whole website in "/stuff" AND "/index.php/stuff" (just the other urls are not at the top of the results). With the permanent redirection, will google reindex the pages with good urls and remove wrong pages or have I to make a canonical url or somthing ?

Comment: Amanite ,ofcourse google will reindex their database with new urls when they see  the permanent redirect. read https://seo-hacker.com/301-302-redirect-affect-seo/

Comment: thanks a lot ! Have you any idea of where would the bad url come from ?